# xim and Japanese/Chinese input methods

Tags: 13.10, input-method, chinese, japanese

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 and I normally use Bépo keyboard layout which requires xim to work properly. I would like to be able to write in Japanese and Chinese. Is there a simple method to use both xim and a Japanese/Chinese input and switch between them easily?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think you can just add Japanese and Chinese input sources, and that it falls back to xim when they aren't used.

Did you try it?

Comment: I did try it with ibus and it didn't work that way. If I'm not mistaken I had to log out to change the input method, which was rather inconvenient.

Comment: @user242479: Please note that the handling of input methods and keyboard layouts is different in 13.10 compared to previous Ubuntu versions. They are integrated into "input sources" and controlled via the "Text Entry" GUI. No, normally you should not need to relogin to change input source. You should be able to e.g. click the input source icon on the menubar and switch instantly. Basically, if I understand it correctly, you should have three items in "Input sources to use" in the "Text Entry" GUI: Bépo, some Chinese method and some Japanese method.

Comment: I've installed ibus again and tried to find an im-config setting for which all those input methods would work. After choosing xim Bépo works correctly, but Chn/Jpn input do not (they work like a regular Qwerty). For all other options the Chn/Jpn inputs work fine, but Bépo doesn't (some characters, e.g. ł, are inaccessible).

Comment: @user242479: Hmm.. There have been quite a few issues with the integration of keyboard layouts and input methods in 13.10. Sounds like you have entered into yet another issue. It would be great if you could file a bug. https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-control-center